# Creating A Continuous Action During A Windows Form Mouse Event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, forms

When I put a button on a form in C#, Visual Studio 2005, and have an action triggered by a button event, such as MouseHover or MouseDown, then the event triggers a single call to the function which defines the action despite the fact that I may continue to hover or keep the left button down.  In this case I am trying to move a graphical object by rotating or translating it.  I don't want to continue to click the mouse in order to get a repeated call to the transforming function, just keep the mouse hovering or hold the button down.  What maintains the action until I cease my own action?

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag on MouseEnter and keep doing the action while the flag remains true. Set the flag to false on MouseLeave.

Comment: I tried the above with the following code:

        private void MouseEnter_ZoomIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            more = true;
            // while (more == true)
            if (more == true)
            {
                c1Chart3D1.ChartArea.View.ViewportScale *= ZoomMultiple;
            }
        }   // MOUSEENTER_ZOOMIN()
        //-------------------------------------
        private void MouseLeave_Stop(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            more = false;
        }

I was hoping that the MouseLeave event would kill the while-loop, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to use a combination of the events MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp.

Here a small simplified example to start:

```
private void OnMouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //hit test to check if the mouse pointer is on a graphical object
   _myHitObject = the_selected_object
}

private void OnMouseMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(_myHitObject != null)
       //do your action relative to the mouse movements.
}

private void OnMouseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _myHitObject = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use DoEvents() which allows for the MouseLeave event to be noted and the class variable "more" to be changed:

private void MouseEnter_ZoomIn(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
 more = true;

 while (more == true)

 {
    c1Chart3D1.ChartArea.View.ViewportScale *= ZoomMultiple;
    Application.DoEvents();

 }
```

} // MOUSEENTER_ZOOMIN()

//-------------------------------------

private void MouseLeave_Stop(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

```
 more = false;
```

}